# How to Auto-connect to wifi hotspot and auto-copy paste from one device to another device?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspicam, android, ios

I have two devices both are compatible with wifi hotspot. One device is collecting pics continuously. When I bring other device with an open wifi hotspot close to the one above, is there a way to make the device auto-connect with the open network and auto copy-paste the pics into the moving device? Assume the devices are rasp pi 3 b or android. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please do some research first before asking, I will vote to close this as to broad.